# webkitTransitionEnd not firing when -webkit-animation completes

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-transitions

thanks in advance for your help, very much appreciated!

I have a CSS progress bar that spins beautifully and a JS function that normalises `transitionEnd`, similar to Modenizer's I believe.

My problem is the `webkitTransitionEnd` event doesn't seem to fire, I'm new to all this so have uploaded a demo of what I'm doing to: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathonoates/99k7r/58/

The demo is using WebKit prefixes only so sorry, you'll have to check it out on Chrome or Safari etc. I'll add in the rest when I get this Webkit version working!

Comment: http://www.orjendev.com/blog/js/css3-transitioneend-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had set the animation to loop infinitely, the animation didn't ever end so it stands to reason `webkitTransitionEnd` isn't being fired.

Additionally, what I really needed was `webkitAnimationEnd` instead.

If you want the animation to loop indefinitely you can either remove the animating classes from the elements in the DOM, set a `timeout` of 0 and then re-add the classes (this isn't ideal) or better still, remove the element(s) from the DOM when the animation completes and re-append them immediately.

Here's the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathonoates/fktqE/2/